# What's the Vertical Asymptote?

Tags: calculus, functions

Find the vertical asymptotes (if any) of the graph of the function. (Use $n$ as an arbitrary integer if necessary.)

$$s(t)= \frac{8t}{\sin{t}}$$

$t= ?$,  where n cannot $=?$

I need a general rule for the asymptotes with where the exception of $n$ is.

Comment: Where does $n$ appear in the question?

Comment: I believe that, as stated, this question can't be understood. Please consider expanding you question and explaining what you mean by "t=? where n cannot =?".

Comment: Sorry about that, n is basically an arbitrary integer, so if the vertical asymptote was n x pi then that would mean any integer multiplied by pi is the vertical asymptote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not allowed to divide by $0$ so $sin(t) = 0$ is an asymptote. So $t = n\pi \quad \forall n \in \mathbb Z - \{ 0 \} $

Comment: that's not an asymptote because t =0 as well then

Comment: is 0 the exception in your notation? There has to be an exception b/c the way the teacher has it set up there must be an exception. I thought it might be 0, but I wasn't 100% sure. All your help is nice tho :)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$ is the set of integers with $0$ removed. So I'm saying it's true for all integers $n$ apart from $n=0$

Comment: Oh ok thank you so much this is very helpful and the electronic way my homework is assigned, it tells you if you have put in the right answer. I put it in and it was correct, so thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A good way to find vertical asymptotes for a function defined as a fraction is to think of where the denominator vanishes, assuming you have the fraction in a factored from. Of course, those aren't the only possibilities for where vertical asymtotes may occur.

Also -- Have you tried graphing the given function? You may notice lots of points where the function values seems to grows very fast.

In your specific problem, you need to find values of $t$ for which

$\sin(t)=0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I tried to graph it and it was a messy graph. I tried to figure it out by looking at the denominator and I think that would be t= n*pi, but I'm not sure what the exception is. I thought it might be 0, but I'm scared that it's wrong and I can't get it wrong again or else I don't get the points. Thanks for the tip tho, I can try to graph it again :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a vertical asymtote, very times that $f(x)\to+\infty$ or $f(x)\to-\infty$, when $x\to a\in \mathbb{R}$, so $x=a$ will be a vertical asymtote.

**Hint:** For which $x\in \mathbb{R}$, you have the $f(x)\to+\infty$ or $f(x)\to-\infty$?

(Try to annul the denominator of the function for "blow up" the function.)